# Copernicus vs Kepler vs truth

Tags: philosophy-of-science, truth

I have always felt uneasy about the step from the Ptolemy to the Copernicus system describes as objective truth.

I note that Thomas Aquinas had the same feeling:

“…Reason is employed in another way, not as furnishing a sufficient proof of a principle, but as confirming an already established principle, by showing the congruity of its results, as in astrology the theory of eccentrics and epicycles is considered as established, because thereby the sensible appearances of the heavenly movements can be explained; not, however, as if this proof were sufficient, forasmuch as some other theory might explain them.” (Reply to Objection 2 question 32, ARTICLE 1, Whether the trinity of the divine persons can be known by natural reason?)

I am not comparing Newtonian mechanics to Ptolemy’s system, rather Copernicus description to Ptolemy’s.  I might just as well include Kepler’s more exact description, (while excluding Kepler laws).
I compare these descriptions to Ptolemy’s and allowing also for a hypothetical improved version of his system. Connotations to Fourier analysis show that improvements of epicycles for both systems is possible to an arbitrary degree of accuracy.

To clarify my point of departure: any description of all the solar system’s masses’ accurate position is as truthful as any other.

I also wonder if the results from set theory define the same situation: using set theory, mathematicians have used for more than a century have many valuable results which all emanate from (essentially a trio of) axioms. The results in set theory do not in themselves prove that the axioms are true (although may come across this idea).

My question is now:

Am I right to argue that position that the Copernican system is not truthful, and similarly the Ptolemy system is not erroneous – from a strict physicalist, realist or materialist position.

Comment: Why are you excluding Kepler's laws and Newtonian mechanics? A big part of sense in which Copernican system is "more true" is that it can be integrated into a greater system that covers much larger set of phenomena than just astronomy, and even paved the way towards its discovery. And Ptolemaic system could not, did not, and hence is "more erroneous". Ultimately, theories are not true or false in isolation, only as parts of a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> "any description of all the solar system’s masses’ accurate position is as truthful as any other."

This was not Copernicus and Kepler's point of view.

According to them, as well as for Ptolemy, there were different *geometrical descriptions* of the celestial bodies' motions that were *mathematically equivalent*.

In spite of this, they can have different "scientific properties", like being more simple etc. See [Copernicus' *De Revolutionibus*, 1543, Preface](http://www.webexhibits.org/calendars/year-text-Copernicus.html) :

> they [different system(s) of deducing the motions of the universe’s spheres] are so uncertain about the motion of the sun and moon that they cannot establish and observe a constant length even for the tropical year. Secondly, in determining the motions not only of these bodies but also of the other five planets, they do not use the same principles, assumptions, and explanations of the apparent revolutions and motions. For while some employ only homocentrics, others utilize eccentrics and epicycles, and yet they do not quite reach their goal.

**But**, there must be only one *physically true* description of reality; see Kepler's [Astronomia nova, seu physica coelestis, tradita commentariis de motibus stellae Martis ex observationibus G.V. Tychonis Brahe (1609)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomia_nova) and [modern commentary](https://books.google.it/books?id=_NZsb6B8ATkC&pg=PA93).

The debate has a long history; see so-called [Conventionalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventionalism#Epistemology) as well as [Pierre Duhem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Duhem)'s *The Aim and Structure of Physical Theory* (*La Théorie Physique. Son Objet, sa Structure*, 1906, Paris).

Answer (score 0):

In statements about the real world, one is often faced with approaches to the truth rather than absolute physical truths.

Ptolemy's cosmology of cycles and epicycles would have been inspired by the likes of the [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism), an ancient portable orrery based on gear ratios and even incorporating epicyclic gears. It was his attempt at the truth.

Copernicus had to be very guarded in his conceptual explanation because the obvious truth of Earth revolving round the Sun was heretical and he had no wish to be branded as such. His public words were defensive sophistry and not an attempt at scientific truth. His truths instead are found in his mathematical approach and its unspoken (at the time) propositions.

Kepler substantially refined the Copernican model, now out in the open, with his ellipses - a new truth, which Newton cemented in place.

Then Einstein's Relativity refined it even more, explaining the precession of Mercury and other niceties. Add in a dash of radiation pressure and that is today's truth.

Who knows what tomorrow will bring?

Each new scientific "truth" edges closer, gives a more accurate model, to the absolute physical truth. That is all that science ever does, it is all that we can ever know.

Your question is somewhat inconsistent, on the one hand noting that the Ptolemaic theory may be refined to achieve arbitrary accuracy, while on the other adjuring us to avoid the details of the Copernican or Newtonian.

Mathematically of course we may use any formula that provides accurate predictions. But that does not mean that two usable formulae are conceptually equivalent. The conceptual basis must be judged in the wider context of scientific knowledge, and here there is no contest.